# How to obtain and count '@gmail.com' from a column of email accounts in SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite

Im trying to obtain and count the number of accounts with a gmail domain. I'm unsure how to do it. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select sum(instr(some_column, '@gmail.com') > 0) as gmail_count
from your_table
```

Comment: hi juergen , which is faster LIKE opeartor or INSTR() function..thnx

Comment: You can try it. Use `explain select ...` and see which query performs better.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as numGmailAccounts
FROM tableName
WHERE emailColumn like '%gmail.com'
```